# Find and replace with sed in directory and sub directories except few directories

Tags: shell

I want to replace foo with bar in a directory structure but I want to skip few folders

I am using this command:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

Comment: "skip few folders", please details which folders you want to skip

Comment: say i want to skip a folder abc, which is present in folder xyz, and xyz contains many folder having multiple files where word foo is presnet

Comment: Your find command should look similar to `find xyz -path "xyz/abc/*" -prune -o -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' '{}' \;` This will search the path starting at `xyz` and *prune* any path beginning with `abc` while applying the `sed` command to the remaining files. You can add additional wildcards within the *prune* structure to broaden the scope of the directories subject to pruning.

Answer (score 0):

You `-prune` to skip directory:

```
 find . -type f -o    \
     \( \( -name unwanted-dir1 -o -name unwanted-dir2 \) -prune -false \)    \
     -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

... or use `-path ./path/to/your-dir` instead of `-name unwanted-dir` if you want to match full path of the unwanted directory...

Comment: its not working i tried by giving a directory path but its not working

Comment: Remember - if you use `-path` option, you have to start with `./` (as your search directory is `.`).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  find . -type f -o    \
>      \( \( -name unwanted-dir1 -o -name unwanted-dir2 \) -prune -false \)    \
>      -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
> ```

This is not working because it's equivalent to

```
 find . -type f -o    \
     \( \( -name unwanted-dir1 -o -name unwanted-dir2 \) -prune -false \) -and \
     -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

since ***-and*** is assumed where the operator is omitted and ***-and*** has higher precedence than ***-o***, so the ***-exec*** is never evaluated.

It works if the ***-type*** test is inside the outer parentheses:

```
 find . \( -type f -o    \
         \( -name unwanted-dir1 -o -name unwanted-dir2 \) -prune -false \)    \
        -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

or, with fewer parentheses:

```
find . \( -name unwanted-dir1 -o -name unwanted-dir2 \) -prune -o    \
       -type f  -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} \;
```

or without parentheses as David C. Rankin suggested in his comment.